# How to get the IP address and other information about someone who tried to log into my Apple account?

Tags: iphone, icloud, password, hacking

A few weeks ago I got a notification on my iPhone that someone from Germany was trying to access and log in to my apple iCloud account.

I think they were successful in figuring out my password, but thankfully I had Two-Factor Authentication on so they couldn't do anything.

So does Apple have a history of login attempts with information: IP, Time, City, device type ...

Comment: You'll have to ask Apple. Because the account was not actually breached because the 2FA did its job, I'm not sure there's any legal reason for Apple to give you the information. Anecdotally, an iPad I'd given my brother years ago was still logged into my  iCloud account, and every so often I'd get the 'attempt to login' email when he'd boot up the iPad. We figured it out and I no longer get the emails. It also could be a spurious login attempt with a mistyped Apple ID email address as well.